# Using ostream with overloading arithmetic operators for class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have class `Rational`, its fragment:

```
class Rational {
private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    void saveAsIrreducible();
    gcd(int x, inty);
public: 
    Rational(int numerator, int denominator=1);
    Rational operator*(Rational &r);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, Rational &r);
}
```

And implementation:

```
Rational::Rational(int numerator, int denominator) {
    this->numerator = numerator;
    this->denominator = denominator;
    this->saveAsIrreducible();
}

Rational Rational::operator*(Rational &r) {
    Rational r2 = Rational((this->numerator*r.numerator), (this->denominator*r.denominator));
    return r2;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, Rational &r) {
    output << r.numerator;

    if(r.denominator!=1)
        output << "|" << r.denominator;

    return output;
}

void Rational::saveAsIrreducible() {
    int greatestCommonDivisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    numerator = numerator/greatestCommonDivisor;
    denominator = denominator/greatestCommonDivisor;
    if(numerator > 0 && denominator < 0) { /* for example for 3|-2, after arithmetic operations */
        numerator = -numerator;
        denominator = -denominator;
    }
}

int Rational::gcd(int x, int y) {
    while(y!=0) {
        int r = x%y;
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }

    return x;
}
```

I have problem with using operator `*` with `cout`. For example, it works:

```
Rational r1(3,5), r2(3,6);
Rational r3 = r1*r2;
cout << r3 << endl;
```

Output is correct. But when I try do this:

```
Rational r1(3,5), r2(3,6);
cout << r1*r2 << endl;
```

I get a lot of errors from the compiler:

```
Rational.cpp|186|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Rational')|

Rational.cpp|186|error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Rational&' from an rvalue of type 'Rational'|
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloaded `operator<<` takes `Rational&` as its argument.

So in the case of the below statements:

```
Rational r3 = r1*r2;
cout << r3 << endl;
```

`r3` is an lvalue (which contains the result of `r1*r2`) whose reference is passed to `operator<<` and it succeeds.

But when you do the below:

```
cout << r1*r2 << endl;
```

You are not passing a reference to `operator<<` because `operator*` is returning a temporary. So it fails.

To resolve this, you can use `const Rational &` as the parameter to `operator<<`.        You will have to change both the declaration and the definition of `operator<<`.

Comment: So every time, when I want to use it, I have to create an object?

Comment: Yes, if you return a temporary from the function.

Comment: Can I somehow avoid this by changing the implementation?

Comment: You can use `const Rational &` as the parameter to `operator<<`. You will have to change both the declaration and the definition of `operator<<`.